# How does Maven deploy work?

Tags: maven, deployment, build

How does maven know which artifacts to deploy? I have a project where i am creating a .war artifact in the build directory and then i rename it to .zip. However, while deploying, it expects to deploy the file .war which doesn't make sense to me. I am a newbie in this domain. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you renaming it to `.zip`? Maven will always deploy the artifact that is defined by it's packaging in the pom.xml.

Comment: I see. I have defined the packaging to be war. However, i need the artifact in zip format because i want to deploy this in a cloud platform that only accepts zip files. I also need the packaging to be war as there is a plugin that i am using that requires the packaging to be war.

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be renamed as opposed to being added to a .zip file? I would think the cloud service would execute an unzip, expecting to find a .war file inside the .zip (along with perhaps other files).